# Php file upload using xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am really confused in using xmlhttprequest. I want to send a file to server. Is it necessary to use formdata to send the file. I am trying to send directly using xmlhttprequest. Instead of getting a file, I am getting only a text at server side.

```
var Stu_Image = localStorage.getItem('StuImage');
alert(Stu_Image);   

nImageRequest[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        nImageRequest[i].open("POST", "http://10.xxx.xx.xx/server/api/upload_image.php", true);
                       // var ImageFile = new Image();
                        ImageFile = "image="+Stu_Image;

                        nImageRequest[i].setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                        alert(ImageFile);
                        nImageRequest[i].onreadystatechange = function (oEvent)
                        {
                         if (nImageRequest[i].readyState == 4)
                         {
                            alert("4 status:"+ nImageRequest[i].status+"-------"+ nImageRequest[i].statusText);
                            if (nImageRequest[i].status == 200)
                            {
                                alert(nImageRequest[i].responseText);
                                return;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                              alert("Error:"+ nImageRequest[i].statusText);
                            }
                         }
                         else
                         {
                         alert("Error:"+ nImageRequest[i].readyState +"----"+nImageRequest[i].statusText);
                         }
                        };

                        nImageRequest[i].send(ImageFile);
```

This is my php file

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 $data = $_POST['image'];

//$data = $_FILES['image']['name'];

echo "".$data;
$fileData = base64_decode($data);
echo ".....".$fileData;


$uploads_dir = "server/api/uploads/";

 move_uploaded_file($fileData, $uploads_dir);

 if(!file_exists($fileData) || !is_uploaded_file($fileData)) 
{
//echo "";
echo "No upload";
}
else
{
 echo "uploaded";
}
```

This is how I got Stu_Image

```
  function loadImage(Value)
   {
         var reader = new FileReader();


            reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("LoadImage").files[0]);
           ImgFile = document.getElementById("LoadImage").files[0];

            /

                         //   alert(ImgFile);

               localStorage.setItem('StuImage',ImgFile);
                alert(ImgFile);


           // alert(url);

               reader.onload = function (Event)
               {


                document.getElementById("PreviewImage").src = Event.target.result;

               };

   };
```

Comment: add your code in post

Comment: my echo "".$data gives me output [objectFile].

Comment: `var ImageFile = new Image(); ImageFile = "image="+Stu_Image;` — You are creating a new image object, then immediately discarding it and replacing it with a string. We have no idea what `Stu_Image` is other than "something you got out of local storage", so there isn't really a whole lot to go on.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to comment it here. I will edit my code above to show where I am getting the "Stu_Image" from.

Comment: Can anyone point out where I am making the mistake ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after wasting a few days, I got the answer to this question. I hope the answer helps someone if he/she gets stuck here.I am not posting the code as it is very big. I was not encoding the image before sending to server.

So the right method is

1 Store Image on Canvas.

2 Encode it using canvas.toDataURL method and send using xmlhttprequest.

3 Decode it as server side. I used php function base64_decode to do it.

4 Use imagecreatefromstring() method to convert decoded string to image and then use imagejpeg() or imagepng() method to get the image.

Hope it helps someone. Happy to post code if required by anyone.